# How to take screenshot on Ubuntu-guest (Virtualbox)

Tags: 10.10, virtualbox, screenshot

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 amd64 in a Virtualbox on windows host. whenever i try to take a screenshot by pressing the print screen or by launching the gnome-screenshot option the screenshot appears completely black.
any idea how to get a screenshot inside the Virtualbox?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok guys! I have found out the problem and the solution. :P

The problem is Compiz and the solution is to disable it using the command:

```
metacity --replace &
```

Now, I can take screenshot of any window inside the VirtualBox.

Comment: Well... this kills all my icons and everything... so partial credit...

Comment: This does not work for me on Mint 17.1 inside Win 8.1. If I use this to try to take a screenshot, I just get a screenshot of my background. It does not matter which application I try to take a picture of (Terminal, Firefox, folder explorer, ...).

Answer (score 4):

VirtualBox provides a menu option to take screenshots of the guest, View --> Take Screenshot (Host+E). Alternatively, just <kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (that's usually <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>).

Comment: These screenshots from View_>Take Screenshot are currently blank(black empty pictures) for me, and doing a Print Screen not even toggled into the Host results in nothing in the copy paste buffer  :(

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu guest go to *System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts*. On the following window define a new shortcut to take a screenshot (e.g. in this example <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>):

[image]

Thenafter a screenshot will be taken whenever you press your keyboard shortcut. The default setting using <kbd>Print</kbd> is not available in the guest (host only).

Taking screenhots will not work with desktop effects activated, i.e. when Compiz is running (see [here for reference](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34411)).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the idea, but even after this , i am unable to take a screenshot with any image. everything is dark in the screenshot. please see the attached screenshot image. http://i.imgur.com/RQkCP.png

Comment: o.k. my fault: I should have read your question better. Your shot is convincing ;). See Edit.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to switch to windowed mode and take a screenshot of the VM window contents from the host OS.

Comment: thanks. yes thats a good idea. i discovered it 2 days back. +1 to u :)

Comment: I've been using this for a long time. It has some limitations. For instance, today I had to take a screenshot of a mouseover effect. Impossible with this method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on windows 7 and you can use the snipping tool to take screenshots on ubuntu guest. I'm on a dual monitor setup though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows 7 running Ubuntu 11.10 on VirtualBox. Taking screenshots doesn't work for me either, but here's a workaround:

Press <kbd>[Host Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.

You can now access the screenshot from the host's (Windows) clipboard. The Host Key is by default <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In VirtualBox 4.2.6 with Windows7-host and Ubuntu12.10-guest, I took correct screen shots before installing Guest Addition tools. After this, I get only black screens and desktop background image.

After disabling VirtualBox 3D acceleration in VM configuration, the problem seems to be gone.

Now I can use <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to take the full screen and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to take a window screen shot through the gnome default capture utility.

Comment: Please detail precisely *what* you did and *how* you did it to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for linux host

Disable "Auto capture keyboard" from virtualbox preferences.

Main virtualbox window (not running guests) -> File -> Preferences -> Input -> Unselect "Auto capture keyboard"